# Regarding Desktop based application Eclipse RCP need to know any obfuscation process

Tags: java, shell, memory-leaks, eclipse-rcp, obfuscation

I am executing some shell commands using java code in my Eclipse RCP application which are saved in memory.
Hacker is able to get the commands from memory using x32dbg tool.
I am unable to hide those commands from memory as they are passed as string.
I wish to create the obfuscated build in my eclipse RCP application which might convert everything in the some special characters format so that if anything would save in memory no body would be able to read it from memory.
My commands are something like this in my class
private static final String COMMAND =
/opt/xyz/scripts/showdata.sh which i execute later by passing in some method.

Comment: Ok @greg-449  apart from this any other solution could you suggest .Does obfuscation can resolve this issue what i understand from obfuscation process is that it makes things in non readable format only for css and html will it works for server side code also.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449 for reply .I think i am not clear in my last statement what i mean to say by server side means. Lets say in java we declare string x ="/opt/scripts/showcdta.sh" so can we can obfusctae the string in some non-readbale format. Currently what i know is obfuscation is normally used for converting html and css to non readable format. The solution to keep commands on server is the last option which i will implement in last

Comment: Thanks @greg-449 i really appreciate your approach .Just like to know one more thing some guys suggested me to keep the shell string in char array which will never be saved in memory .Will this approach works for me .

Comment: @greg-449 Could you please help me to do java obfuscation . I would like to try once using java obfuscation .

Comment: @greg-449 Is there any option in eclipse plugin development that we can disable generation of pdb files if  pdb files are not generated then i believe  no  debugger tool can be attached to the application . After using Export Product option i created the set up using JET tool. Could you suggest how can i disable the pdb files generation

Comment: Hi @greg-449 one last query regarding the RCP desktop application from next year microsoft will stop supporting the IE browser will the eclipse RCP desktop applications developed 5 or 6 years back will stop working are the desktop application depends upon IE browser

Comment: @greg-449 I really did not get the meaning of SWT browser in the code. In my code we are using like SWT.NONE,SWT.FILL,,SWT.PUSH .Could you please provide more info on SWT Broswer or any code which i can check in my code .Or you are saying for the library org.eclipse.swt.browser

Comment: @greg-449  Ok i checked this Browser control is not used in my code so it means my application will work next year even if the Microsoft will stop supporting IE browser

Comment: Hi @greg-449 I need some support in my project i need some help related to extension point in eclipse rcp project could you please help me  may i have urs skype id pls

Comment: ok @greg-449  Actually i need some help related to extension point
I wish to pass some parameter to the class A which is called automatically . For example class A is called using extension points class B is loading com.tofconfig.configprovider.exsd file so moment the class B is called the Class A is automatically called i need to pass some identifier in class A to identify on which button click its called .Currently theere two buttons which calling Class B and passing also identifier in class B but how to forward identifier inside the Class A from class B thats question

Comment: Hi @greg-449 i am facing one challenge after the implementation of urls which i discussed earlier.I made the changes as per your suggestion that all the urls i put to the server and then i started called simply on common function server in which i pass the code and  and w.r.t to code that url executes .But issue is that due to this implementation i am unable to support backward comptability .It will work for newer releases but will not work with older server builds.Could you please suggest something